# MassTransit selective consumers without round tripping

Tags: masstransit

I am looking at using masstransit and have a need for selectively sending messages to consumers at the end if unreliable and slow network links (they are in the same WAN but use a slow and expensive cellular link).

I am expecting a fanout of 1 to 200 where the sites with lowest volume of messages and least reliable / most expensive links need to ignore the potentially high amount of message traffic othe consumers will see

I have looked at using the Selective consumer interface but this seems to imply that the message is always sent to all consumers, and then discarded if it doesn't match the predicate. This overhead is not acceptable.

Without using endpoint factory and manually managing uri end points to do a Send(), is there a nice way to do thus using subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: nope.

You do have a few options though. Is it just routing based upon load/processing? You could use competing consumers to do load balancing. All the endpoints read off the same queue (but they must be the same consumers on every process reading from the queue) and just pick up the next one. If you're slow, you just pick off fewer messages. (You can only use competing consumers with RabbitMQ).

For MSMQ there's a distributor that was built for load balancing. You could look at rebuilding that on top of RabbitMQ that if that's your transport. It's not super complicated, but would take some effort to do.

Other than that, I think you're likely down to writing something from scratch. It's not really pub/sub any more. So it falls outside MT's wheelhouse.